# How could I add my web browser game to Adsense?

Tags: browser, adsense

I tried to add my recently published web browser game to adsense. However, they rejected it and replied with needs attention, your site doesn't have any content.
How can I make it approved by adsense? Because it is a web browser game, it is quite normal that there is no content like blogs
Is there any alternative way to make my site publish any advertising by adsense, or any alternative for adsense that can allow web browser games?

Answer (score 0):

Hey AdSense is for Unique and Informative text content. In online game nothing unique or text. So I will suggest you to create app and use AdMob or try AdX.